# How to POST selected tabulator row data to another page?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am trying to get the selected row data from the tabulator and then post it as an array to a separate page.
I have found how to print data to the console, but how can I add this data to an array and then POST it to a separate page?

This is what I currently have

```js
document.getElementById("get-selected").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var selectedData = table.getSelectedData();
    jQuery.map(selectedData, function(value, index) {
        console.log(value.FirstName);
        console.log(value.LastName);
        console.log(value.Age);
    });
});
```

I have been looking on google for hours but I can't find any examples of what I am trying to do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Matt, could you please elaborate a bit more like what you have achieved from this code and the expected output for further steps.

Comment: PHP does this very easily using $_POST.  You can likely find a multitude of examples on your favorite video streaming app, just search ***how to POST form data to another page using PHP***.

Comment: I want to POST the selected tabulator rows to another page using ajax POST, but I don't know how to get the data from jQuery.map into an array that I can send.

$.ajax({
     url: 'includes/page2.php,
     type: "post",
     data: { data: 'selectedRows' },
     success: function(response) {
     }
});

Comment: You are using `document.getElementById("get-selected")` then no need to continue with jQuery. `document.getElementById("get-selected").addEventListener("click", () => { let selectedData = table.getSelectedData(); const arr = selectedData.map(({FirstName,LastName,Age}) => ({FirstName,LastName,Age})); /* here you can use fetch to post or use $.post */
 });`